# html svg - weird color of cursor "crosshair" hovering svg elements

Tags: html, svg

The color of the mouse cursor ("crosshair") changes when hovering an svg element which has color. I observed this behaviour on Chrome and FF.

Minimal Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/GPQWjRW7d9e5Nk1wq8QG?p=preview

If you move the mouse cursor over the circles, the color of the crosshair changes. I would like to have the crosshair staying black regardless of the color of the underlying element or control the color of the crosshair with respect to the color of the shape. Do you have an idea why this behaviour occurs (since the default cursor does not change the color on hover) ? Is there a workaround / way to fix this ?

**Intention:** I have a svg element (fixed color) with an opacity. When hovering it the crosshair results in a color which could indicate that the cursor is behind (z-index) the element and i would like to avoid that.

A pseudo-container as parent of the svg with the CSS attribute `cursor : crosshair` does not help.

Thank you for your effort.

Comment: You really want a black cursor if you have a black shape? What use would that be? Anyway if you do want one, create your own custom cursor and use that.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I edited my question/plunker according to state my intention. I understand that (from a usability perspective) the color has to change given certain color compositions (cursor vs. pixel). But if you think about an element with opacity, the cursor's z-position could be misinterpreted. Creating my own cursor is indeed a possibility.